# What is the true row limit for bigquery "Download as CSV"?

Tags: google-bigquery

The BigQuery [Browser tool documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/browser_tool#exportdata) mentions the limit on CSV exports:

> If a query result set has fewer than 16,000 rows, you can download it
>   as a CSV file.

We've tried this feature and the limit appears to be much smaller than 16,000 rows. Using this query:

```
SELECT 
  contract_id,
  product,
  AVG(element_value)
FROM [******.payout]
GROUP BY contract_id, product
LIMIT 600;
```

The UI responds with an error:

> This result set contains too many rows for direct download. Please use
>   "Save as Table" and then export...

If I reduce the LIMIT to 500, then the CSV download works.

Can you please confirm the actual row limit.  Is the documentation out of date, or is this a bug in the query interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the UI -- download as CSV should work with up to 16k rows (or 10 MB of results). This has been fixed internally and the fix should go out with next week's release.